# error:request entitiy is too large in nodejs when uploading the image

Tags: node.js

error:request entitiy is too large in nodejs 
Whenever updating the image in mean stack full program.image with smaller size is updating and for image with 800kb
plz fix the error
thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using expressjs?

Comment: yes @http://stackoverflow.com/users/449897/santosh-singh

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the upload limit by using following code snippet.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ...

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb'}));
```

Comment: Tried as said by http://stackoverflow.com/users/449897/santosh-singh.But it is not supporting for my images in high quality